# Directing non-www to www by NGINX did not work?

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I'm deploying a website with NGINX and Wordpress.
To redirect from non-www to www, I put some code to NGINX config:

```
if ($host = example.com) {
    return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
}
```

I checked with Curl:

```
curl http://example.com
Result:
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Mon, 03 Jun 2019 16:19:28 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 194
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://www.example.com/
```

But browser address bar still shows: **https://example.com/**.

I have to change URL setting in Wordpress General from **example.com** to **www.example.com**, browser address bar will shows: **https://www.example.com/** as what I expected.

So:

Why I have to redirect non-www to www in 2 places (in NGINX and Wordpress Setting)?

Comment: `http != https`

Comment: Please check `curl https://example.com/` as well.